# Changing line width for drawing into canvas (gwt)

Tags: gwt, canvas

I have a method that draws a hexaon into my canvas.

```
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(points.get(0).X(), points.get(0).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(1).X(), points.get(1).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(2).X(), points.get(2).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(3).X(), points.get(3).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(4).X(), points.get(4).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(5).X(), points.get(5).Y());
    context.lineTo(points.get(0).X(), points.get(0).Y());
    context.stroke();
```

How could I control width of the line I draw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are looking for:

```
context.setLineWidth(10);
```